# Grow words from fertile vocabularies

Tags: code-golf, graph-theory, word

An *incremental word chain* is a sequence of words of a vocabulary such that each word is the result of either prepending or appending a single character to the previous word, ignoring capitalization. An example of such a chain can be found below.

> I → is → his → hiss

Your task is to write a program that for a given vocabulary finds the longest incremental word chain. The input is provided from standard input a vocabulary as one word per line. The words are composed of the lowercase letters a to z only. The output of your program shall go to standard output and shall be one word per line a longest word chain of the input vocabulary, starting with the shortest word.

This is code golf, the solution with the least character count wins. Different forms of input or output are not possible, but the terms *standard input* and *standard output* may be interpreted in a reasonable way for the language you are solving this problem in.

Please demonstrate that your code works by publishing the longest word chain you find on the xz-compressed vocabulary found [here](http://fuz.su/~fuz/files/voc.xz). This vocabulary was generated by executing the following series of commands on the file *british-english-insane* from the [SCOWL project](http://wordlist.aspell.net/) in the C locale:

```
tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' <british-english-insane | sed -n '/^[a-z]*$/p' | sort -u | xz -9e >voc.xz
```

A solution in polynomial time is possible and highly appreciated.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I agree with you that these challenges are similar, but an important difference is that in my challenge the graph is acyclic, so a solution in polynomial time can be found.

Comment: Title and description don't match, as the title allows only appending whereas the description also allows prepending. Description trumps title, doesn't it?

Comment: @nimi You are correct. To put it simply, I didn't find a formulation of the problem that fits in the title and is correct. Maybe you can help me find one?

Comment: FUZxxi,  How about "Growing Words"?

Comment: @DavidCarraher Better this way?

Comment: Yes, I think it is better.  Calls attention nicely.

Comment: Is the input supposed to be the actual words, the name of a file containing the words, or something else?

Comment: @KSFT The input is a newline separated list of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Ruby <s>139</s> 127

```rb
h={}
$<.map{|l|h[l.strip]=1}
v=->w,c=[]{w<?a?c:h[w]&&(v[w.chop,z=[w]+c]||v[w[1..-1],z])}
puts h.map{|k,_|v[k]||0}.max_by &:size
```

Runs in ~3.5 seconds and prints:

```
r
ra
rah
rahm
brahm
brahma
brahman
brahmani
brahmanis
brahmanism
brahmanisms
```

Comment: @britishtea fixed!

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 127

Runs in about 6.5 seconds. Uses a couple of cool tricks. ARGF (`$<` or stdin, really) is enumerable! If an array is passed as a block argument, it can be "exploded" and assigned to a parameter using `{|w,| ... }`. Notice the comma.

I found an even shorter solution which uses `Array#&` (set intersection) to do the lookup of words, but that runs extremely slow, unfortunately.

Thanks to w0lf for shaving off a few characters

```ruby
D={}
$<.map{|l|D[l.strip!]=l}
puts D.map{|w,|c=[w]
w.chars.all?{w=c[0]
r=D[w.chop]||D[w[1..-1]]
r ?c=[r]+c :p}
c}.max_by &:size
```

#### Output

```
r
ra
rah
rahm
brahm
brahma
brahman
brahmani
brahmanis
brahmanism
brahmanisms
```

#### Readable version

```ruby
D = {}
$<.lines { |l| D[l.strip] = l.strip }

chains = D.map do |word, _|
  chain = [word]

  word.chars.all? do
    word   = c.first
    result = D[w.chop] || D[w[1..-1]]

    result ? chain.unshift(result) : nil
  end
end

puts chains.max_by(&:size)
```

Comment: Nice! You can save some more chars: `max_by(&:size)` --> `max_by &:size` and `r ?c.unshift(r):p}` --> `r ?c=[r]+c :p}`

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 208 bytes

Here is a not very small solution. It firsts creates an index of the word parts, then recursively searches for the longest chain.

```
import sys
d={}
b=lambda k:d.setdefault(k,[]).append(e)
for e in sys.stdin:e=e[:-1];b(e[1:]);b(e[:-1])
def f(a):
 g=a
 for c in d.get(a[-1],[]):g=max(g,f(a+[c]),key=len)
 return g
for e in f([''])[1:]:print e
```

It returns:

```
a
ab
rab
arab
arabi
arabin
arabine
carabine
carabiner
carabinero
carabineros
```

in 6.2 seconds.

The code before minifier looks like this:

```
import sys

lookup = {}
addindex = lambda k: lookup.setdefault(k, []).append(word)

for word in sys.stdin :
    word = word[:-1];
    addindex(word[1:]);
    addindex(word[:-1])
print 'Indexed' # DEBUG

def find(wordlist):
    best = wordlist
    for newword in lookup.get(wordlist[-1], []) :
        best = max(best, find(wordlist+[newword]), key=len)
    return best

for word in find([''])[1:] :
    print word
```

Comment: Please read from standard input and write the entire chain to standard output.

Comment: Now uses stdin. I found a way to save a few bytes too.

Comment: Your program is still incorrect. It has to print the entire chain, not just the last word in it. Also, it has to print the word chain in the format specified in the question.

Comment: I take it that I am now presenting in the correct format?

Comment: I hope the down-voter is more pleased with the improved answer :-)

Comment: Yeah, the current format looks good.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 175 Bytes

```
import Data.Set
main=interact$unlines.snd.maximum.g.lines
g l=Prelude.map(f(0,[]))l where f z@(d,r)w|notMember w(fromList l)=z|1<2=max(f(d+1,w:r)(tail w))(f(d+1,w:r)(init w))
```

finds

```
r
ra
ran
fran
franc
franci
francis
francisc
francisca
franciscan
franciscans
```

Spent about 30 bytes for the use of a `Set` data structure for efficient lookups but that are useless (in code golf!) otherwise.

How it works: for every word from the input build recursively a list with valid child words. Take the longest list and print it. A "child word" is the word with either first or last letter missing. It is "valid" if it's in the input. If both child words exist, take the one that builds the longer sublist.

Comment: "r" is not a word, so isn't this solution invalid?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork It's part of the given dictionary.

Comment: @agweber:  My goodness, "r" is now in the dictionary.  I programmed in *Mathematica* an interesting, related problem (longest sequence of words where an insertion could occur *anywhere*) and, using the WordData all led to either "i" or "a".

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Even if "r" is not a word the `a → ra` chain is still valid :)

Answer (score 1):

**J: 246 bytes**

```
's p'=:(*(>./i)>:])|:(6 s:[:s:}.;}:)S:0 w[i=:6 s:v=:s:w=:~.a:,<;._2 fread'voc'
l=:[:,([:(#S:0)5 s:_6 s:])"0
f=:3 :'(y{~])^:(~:0:)^:a:"0 y'
q=:_6 s:]
d=:[:+/@:*"1 f
ds=:d s[dp=:d p
n=:(ds<:dp)}s,:p[m=:ds>.dp
echo}:"1 q(r{i),.(r=:([:I.]=>./)m){f n
```

output:

```
`franciscans `franciscan `francisca `francisc `francis `franci `franc `fran `fra `fr `f
```

[Version with comments.](https://github.com/tangentstorm/tangentlabs/blob/master/j/growvoc.ijs)

Comment: Please obey the output format.

Comment: Also, why is this community wiki?

Comment: So someone else can edit it if they want. It's not really well golfed and I don't have time to work on it.